# Returning singular child element with parent element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

Heres what I'm trying to do:

I want to go through the users positions, and then use those to loop through the offices that have the positions assigned to them and return only the office and the position the user is.

This is what I've tried, i know it's redundant and just goes through all of the offices and filters it by users positions and returns the same exact result as `userPositions`, i just can't figure out how to go through them and grab the position within the office and return only the offices & office.positions that have their id == the user positions.id

```js
    filter(){
      var userPositions = this.users.positions;
      var offices = this.offices;
      var filter = []
      var position = offices.forEach(office => {
        office.positions.forEach(position => {
          filter.push(position)
        })
      });
      userPositions.forEach(userP => {
        filter.find(p => p.id === userP.id)
      })
      console.log(filter)
    }
```

Heres how I want it to look:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leadership Committee",
        "abbreviation": "LC",
        "positions": [
            {
                "id": 122,
                "name": "Deputy Director",
                "abbreviation": "DD",
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Admin Committee",
        "abbreviation": "AC",
        "positions": [
            {
                "id": 124,
                "name": "Director",
                "abbreviation": "Dir",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is the user.positions info:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "Admin",
    "status": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-07-23 21:49:56",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-30 07:22:17",
    "positions": [
        {
            "id": 124,
            "name": "Director",
            "abbreviation": "Dir",
        },
        {
            "id": 122,
            "name": "Deputy Director",
            "abbreviation": "DD",
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is how grabbing all the offices look:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leadership Comittee",
        "abbreviation": "LC",
        "positions": [
            {
                "id": 119,
                "name": "Director",
                "abbreviation": "Dir",
                "pivot": {
                    "office": 1,
                    "position": 119,
                    "hierarchy": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 122,
                "name": "Deputy Director",
                "abbreviation": "DD",
                "pivot": {
                    "office": 1,
                    "position": 122,
                    "hierarchy": 2
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Admin Comittee",
        "abbreviation": "AC",
        "positions": [
            {
                "id": 124,
                "name": "Director",
                "abbreviation": "Dir",
                "pivot": {
                    "office": 10,
                    "position": 124,
                    "hierarchy": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem statement simplified.

> Given 2 source arrays, say source1 and source2 , return all source2
>   array elements that relates to a specific field in source1.
>
> **Relation**: field in source1 should match one element of a nested array
>   field in source2
>
> **Constraint**: elements in  source2 array should be modified before
>   returning as per the relation above

**Level 1:**  Loop through all the source1 elements  (`user.positions` in your case). Here I used `Array.prototype.reduce` to start with because, my final return array might be smaller in size than `source1` array, if I could not find a related element in  `source2`. In your case, no positions found in any offices.

**Level 2:** Inside the `Array.prototype.reduce` function, for each element of `source1` (each user position in your case) return a matching element in `source2` array. In this case I used  `Array.prototype.map` function because, the **constraint** says that elements in `source2` array should be modified.

**Level 3:** Inside the `Array.prototype.map` function, modify each element of `source2` (each office in this case). I’m applying the relation inside the map function, to modify each element in `source2`(each office). In your case, I’m modifying the positions property  of each office, applying the `Array.prototype.filter` function on office positions array with user position object.

The filter might give an empty array or a subarray of office positions array which is used to replace the original office positions array itself. Each filtered object can also be modified using a map function to remove some unwanted fields. In your case I removed pivot from each office position object.

Level 4: Remove all the modified `source2` objects whose positions property is an empty array.

Putting it all together...

```js
var data = {
  users: {
    id: 1,
    username: "Admin",
    status: 1,
    created_at: "2019-07-23 21:49:56",
    updated_at: "2019-08-30 07:22:17",
    positions: [
      {
        id: 124,
        name: "Director",
        abbreviation: "Dir"
      },
      {
        id: 122,
        name: "Deputy Director",
        abbreviation: "DD"
      }
    ]
  },
  offices: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Leadership Comittee",
      abbreviation: "LC",
      positions: [
        {
          id: 119,
          name: "Director",
          abbreviation: "Dir",
          pivot: {
            office: 1,
            position: 119,
            hierarchy: 1
          }
        },
        {
          id: 122,
          name: "Deputy Director",
          abbreviation: "DD",
          pivot: {
            office: 1,
            position: 122,
            hierarchy: 2
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      name: "Admin Comittee",
      abbreviation: "AC",
      positions: [
        {
          id: 124,
          name: "Director",
          abbreviation: "Dir",
          pivot: {
            office: 10,
            position: 124,
            hierarchy: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  filter() {
    return this.users.positions.reduce((acc, userPosition) => {
        acc = [
          ...acc,
          ...this.offices
            .map(office => {
              return {
                ...office,
                positions: office.positions
                  .filter(
                    officePosition => officePosition.id === userPosition.id
                  )
                  .map(({ pivot, ...rest }) => rest)
              };
            })
            .filter(office => office.positions.length > 0)
        ];
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }
};

console.log(data.filter());
```

Comment: This works perfectly!!!! Thank you! Could you explain to me how it works? I understand some of it buy still don't fully understand it and I would like to know.

Comment: @Riley Definitely, I will update the answer with explanations

Comment: @Riley. Please check the updated answer. Let me know if still not clear